# Outline the selected row in a jqgrid instead of changing it's color

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I am looking to outline my JGGrid when a row is selected with a red outline instead of just changing the color row. Can you please help me achieve this ? is there no existing JQUERY UI class that does the job ?

Old format : 
[Old format](http://picpaste.com/pics/grid1-mAahEqxp.1463489403.png)

Wanted format:
[The way i want selections to be](http://picpaste.com/pics/grid2-ywHXZurw.1463489515.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post a code in fiddle.

Comment: @maverickosama92 this is not my example, this is a random fiddle, but it shows what i want, http://jsfiddle.net/amorris/ynw3c/ . Select a row and you'll understand .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

you could override this method in jqgrid:

```
onSelectRow:function(rowid){
   //gets all rows and remove custom class
   var $trs = $("#grid tbody tr").removeClass("custom-class");

   //only set custom class to current row clicked
   $trs.eq(rowid).addClass("custom-class");      
}
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/13655

Comment: @zouza: check this

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I have figured out this so far, what bothers me is how to select only the row not the cells in a decent way, in your answer your custom class selects the cell's border, i just want the row selected. Thanks

Comment: @zouza: its selecting full row and cells are selected as red because the td css inherits the css from tr

Comment: I tried doing it with the outline attribute but it only worked on the top and bottom sides of the row, left and right didn't change color  outline: #00FF00 dotted thick;

Comment: I understand but that's what i don't want, i only want the row and not the cells selected, maybe with outline property  ?  i tried but i didn't succeed

Comment: Perfect !! Thanks.

Comment: i want to accept your answer but you put it as a comment. How can i do ?

Comment: I updated the fiddle link above. You can see and accept it.

Comment: i hope u still remember the issue, and hope u still can help me, i  can't seem to be able to display the red border locally on my computer, i used the exact same code ? can u still help me ? i know i closed the question but ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS rule like

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv .ui-state-highlight {
    outline: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

or

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv .ui-state-highlight {
    border: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Oleg but neither of the two does what i want , in fact the solution seems to be the combination of the two. I do not want the cells to be colored in red, just the outer borders => first left, last right top and bottom. Thank you anyway, maverickosama92 's last answer did the Job. Thank you

Comment: sorry for the previous comment, in fact your answer maybe the right one, i tested it on the example in the fiddle it worked, but locally on my machine some thing is wrong the upper border doesn't color with red, nor the left one, the other are perfect. Does this have to do with my grid's config ?

Comment: this is what's happening on my machine http://picpaste.com/pics/grid3-zpr6NkG4.1463496155.png

Comment: @zouza: You are welcome! Do you tried my suggestion? Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa-background.htm). The result of selection of the row are practically the same like on the pictures. jqGrid set `ui-state-highlight` class **automatically** on the selected rows.

Comment: using the outline property, can we not select the left side and right side borders of the line ?

Comment: @zouza: It's correct, but it's good so. What is your goal? I think you want the the user can see more clear the selected row. The `outline: 1px solid tomato;` do this. The grid consist from relatively complex structure of dives and tables. Inserting or removing of border somewhere can break calculation of the width of some internal elements. Thus I recommend you don't change the existing behavior and just use CSS rule like `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv .ui-state-highlight { outline: 1px solid tomato; }`

Comment: Thank you for your time, I need to select all the row for visibility reasons, check this image and you'll understand me maybe . http://picpaste.com/pics/grid4-vvbnQGi6.1463497540.png

Comment: in the picture above the selected row is highlighted with grey, i don't want that i want to outline it in red but i want to do that for all the borders not just top and bottom please.

Comment: moreover in your demo if you select the last line only the upper border is colored in red. I know it's the grid's behavior but  can we not have it select all the row's  borders ?